# System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class works differently depending on target framework

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, serial-port, .net-standard

I am trying to open a serial port connection to a bluetooth device.  This is the way i have decided to do it, as my device communicates over rfcomm and there isnt very good library support for bluetooth.

The issue is, I can run the exact same code, targeting different frameworks, and receive different results.  When I am targeting .NET Framework (4.5), no issues, works as expected.  When I am targeting .NET Standard (2.0), I typically get the warning

Warning: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.

The warning is clear, but I do not know where the other assembly could be, as I made a basic application from scratch.

Here is a code sample:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
bool bConnected = false;
string sComPort = "COM10";
WindowsBluetoothSocket = new SerialPort(sComPort);
WindowsBluetoothSocket.Open();
bConnected = WindowsBluetoothSocket.IsOpen;
```

If you use the same code provided in a .NET framework console application, you should have no issues.  If you use it in a Xamarin.Forms mobile app just for UWP (.NET Standard 2.0) it will fail as described.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "it will fail as described." - you haven't described any failures.  You just stated you are getting a compiler warning.  Are you using any nuget packages or other libraries?

Comment: A class is like a path name that consists of folders and finally a filename.  The class has a series of Namespaces followed by a class name.  So  you can have more than one class with the same name, but with different parent namespaces.  Normally you can just specify the class name and the compiler will locate the class without specifying the namespace(s).  When you have duplicate class names you must specify the namespaces to identify the class you want to use.  The warning is indicating in some versions of Net the class you are using is found in more than one library (namespace).

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough.  I have added a reference to System.IO.Ports (version 5.0.0.0) from nuget to both.  Without that the xamarin version will try to use System instead (which still causes the same issue). The actual issue happens when you call WindowsBluetoothSocket.Open().  Xamarin will fail since it thinks there are multiple versions, while the .NET Framework version will not.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you look at the SerialPort Class at learn.Microsoft.com/...etc.   it tells you at the bottom that SerialPort will work on Xamarin Mac3.0.  I think this means it will not work on Android and UniversalWindows, only Mac3.iOS.  I ran into the same problem you described and could not figure out why it coded without errors yet still did not work on the UniversalWindows project.

Comment: Hmm, that's a different issue.  UWP has its own idea about how serial ports should be used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication?view=winrt-22621