# Connecting to USB Serial Port Xamarin Forms Android and UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, serial-port, usb

I am trying to write a cross platform application using Xamarin that will work on Windows and Android that receives data via Serial port, through USB.

I tried System.IO.Ports but it would say FileNotFound Exception on UWP. I also tried other nuget packages without success. One that said  it worked for linux but raised AccessDenied Exception (it was opening 2 ports simultaneously). Is this possible to do with Xamarin?

Comment: These articles may be helpful. [System.IO.Ports 5.0 Xamarin.Forms Serial Port not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64774350/9014308), [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class works differently depending on target framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65081613/9014308), [Top 20 NuGet serialport Packages](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/serialport)

Answer (score 0):

This USB Host API, to Communicate with USB Hardware, you can use for Android. https://github.com/anotherlab/UsbSerialForAndroid.